# Selective printout from file

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write program, who's printout specific words (without "e"). But i have a problems.
that's my code:

```py
def has_no_e(fin,word):
fin = open('words.txt')
for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    if 'e' not in word:
        print(word)
    else:
        continue

print(has_no_e)
```

Pycharm after run it printout that:

> function has_no_e at 0x00E078A0

I don't know what's wrong. Thanks everybody for any help.

Comment: Your last line should just be `has_no_e()` without the print

Comment: Why did you declare `has_no_e()` to accept two parameters, when you don't actually use them?

Answer (score 1):

Try `has_no_e(<fin>, <word>)`, without the `print`. What you're doing there is printing the function address itself, if you try doing `has_no_e(<fin>, <word>)` the function contents will be executed instead, which is what you want.

P.S. Replace fin and word with the actual parameters you want to pass.

Comment: `has_no_e()` will be an error, because it's missing required parameters.